# Can you suggest a presentation slide page editor for a webapplication? (WYSIWYG but not HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor

I'm designing a web application that allows editing pages. The catch is, its not HTML content, its not even to be shown in a webpage besides the WYSIWYG editor.

Its more specifically **presentation slides for non-rectangular LED signage displays** (custom hardware) of low resolution:
[image: example GUI for presentation slide page in the editor]

*(above screenshot happens to be rectangular, but displays often have a custom shape)*

The page editing should more resemble Powerpoint than TinyMCE, so to say. For example, inline "content elements" such as a time (or image, or counter, or tickertape text) can be altered by the user within the page.

And sometimes reposition is disallowed, turning the page to a template which only allows users to vary text and some appearance settings.

**Can you suggest such a "presentation slide page editor" for a web application?**

If you are going to suggest TinyMCE or the like, please specify what enables these to do inline (or floating) content elements, and whether it allows pixel-perfect editing as shown in my screenshot.

.. i am guessing there is no such thing, and i'd have to build something from scratch. In that case i'd likely go for a simple template design where the users fills in fields and a bitmap preview is rendered serverside.

Comment: If you voted to close this question, please comment to explain why.. i am NOT looking for another WYSIWYG HTML editor! This is a very specific set of requirements for a JS library / GUI component, i welcome insights to investigate as i found none.

Comment: What specific WYSIWYG-like features are you looking for? Do you have fonts that can be used for the text (i.e. use them as web fonts) or do you need to be able to draw the characters/graphics pixel by pixel? Are these graphics defined somewhere? It seems like you'll probably have to build your own, but these are some questions to consider.

Comment: The graphics are all defined in the hardware, and i'll have to match those. Every font, every pixel. There even are animations and transitions i'd like to reproduce in web, but thats another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I feel like you're going to need to write something custom for this. I'm guessing that [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas) would probably be best for this. That would involve having to draw everything onto the canvas, but it would give you good pixel perfection. It seems like that would be best if you want to emulate how the marquee display will render it. In terms of text editing, you could use some sort of input for that (WYSIWYG or not) and then just render it within a canvas element. I'm sure it's possible to emulate a cursor and to capture keyboard input to "write" directly to the canvas component, but that might be more work.

Comment: I like how `canvas` gives me full control. Perhaps to learn how to render and catch input i might need to make a HTML5 game first as POC..

Comment: Update: i forgot about this question but what i ended up doing is indeed writing something custom. We use React so i built a Preview component that renders an item (JS object) thats passed as a property. In turn this presentation component does callback for user-actions, does smart scaling and color mapping, and has built in selection indication. This preview component in turn is used in a editor component, that also contains a property-editor for selected elements, and a element-selection-list component. Its truly excellent if i may so so myself. Thanks to React and HTML5 canvas.